# Keyed Tuple is not returning while doing select queries with dbobject.query.with_entities(dbobject.col1,dbobject2) in Flask SqlAlchamey

Tags: python, flask, swagger, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I'm working in swagger with Flask application. In that i'm trying to create API response. So i tried the below stuff.

I have a table with 15 columns. I just wanted to select only particular columns from the table. So i used `with_entities()` from sqlalchemy like below.

```
dbobject.query.with_entities(dbobject.id, dbobject.name, dbobject.version)
```

It is returning the available rows from table in this format for all rows `(21, asset21, 9898)` but not as keyed tuple. Also `row.__table__.columns.keys()` is not working when i tried to get column names for selected rows from the returned rows of above query. It just endup with below error

```
    for col in row.__table__.columns.keys() if col != 'id')
AttributeError: 'result' object has no attribute '__table__'
```

But `row.__table__.columns.keys()` the same snippet is working when i do select all columns from table `dbobject.query.all()`

Any specific reason why it is not working for with_entities?

Comment: You probably just want to use column bundles instead, see http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_columns.html#column-bundles

Comment: I tried but end up with below  error, I don't want to filter anything. I just required to select all rows of that given columns.                                                                                return cls.query(bn)
TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable

Comment: to use column bundles you need to use `session.query()` method, instead of `cls.query` property; also you could try `cls.query.with_entities(bn)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Labeling should give the end result as expected

```
dbobject.query.with_entities(dbobject.id.label('id'), dbobject.name.label('name'), dbobject.version.label('version'))
```